How to recombine object based on restricted typed values passed into a function
I am trying to refactor some code where a function returns a different type of content based on the key I pass in, and I need to put together a function signature that will be able to accept different types of content based on what key it is.
A simpler example that demonstrates my issue is the following:
type OptionA = { type: 'A'; val: number };
type OptionB = { type: 'B'; val: string };
type Option = OptionA | OptionB;

function give<T extends Option['type']>(type: T, val: Extract<Option, { type: T }>['val']) {
    take({ type, val });
}

function take(o: Option) {
    console.log(o);
}

This code to me seems to have no possible typing issues as the only ways to use the give function are as such:
give('A', 1) // No error
give('B', 'a') // No error

give('A', 'a')
// Warning: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)

give('B', 1)
// Warning: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)

How could I possibly update the function type signature to remove this warning?
Edit: After further testing, I've realised that the give function signature can be simplified to the following without changing the error:
function give<T extends Option>(type: T['type'], val: T['val']) {
  take({ type, val });
}


TS can't follow the logic of generic conditional types like this. If you want to express this operation in a way TS understands it, you need to refactor to generic indices into mapped types as shown in this playground link, as described in ms/TS#47109. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

I've looked at this solution, but the issue is that I cannot change the type signature of the take function. I probably should specify that in the question. The playground link only works by modifying both functions' signatures.

If you can't change the take() signature then you're going to need a type assertion (e.g., {type, val} as Option), since TypeScript cannot make the leap from generic to union in the way you want. This is ms/TS#30581 and ms/TS#47109 above. There's little to be done here other than refactoring types/signatures or loosening type safety, unfortunately. So as far as I know it still fully addresses the question, even if it isn't what you wanted to hear. Shall I write an answer explaining or not?

I managed to make a solution without forced type casting, but it does change the function slightly so it is not the most ideal answer.
Due to the nature of my actual issue, I was able to change the first argument to the give function to a base version of the object. Then the function can be written as such with no type errors:
function give<T extends Option>(option: T, val: T['val']) {
  take({ ...option, val } satisfies T);
}

Note that the use of satisfies here does not count as true type cast.

I'm wondering why you self-accepted this if you don't think it's ideal. I had suggested this version. If it meets your needs I'd be happy to write an answer to explain how it works. If not, could you explain why?
